# Can you initialize an array in a return statement in C++ using curly brackets?

Tags: c++, arrays, return

for instance can i say:

```
    return new int returnValue[3] = {0,1,2};
```

or is this invalid code? what would be the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

This is legal

```
int* foo(){
  return new int[3]{0,1,2};
}
```

Next time, you could always just try it on your own and play with it a little bit.